# Chart.js unable to display data

Tags: javascript, arrays, codeigniter, arraylist, chart.js

I have here the code of my chart, I am trying to display a chart however I am getting my values on label from another function (the output of that function is the var label3, if I will use label3 as my labels on the chart it will not work, but if I use the format like label2 it will work.
My question is how can I make label3 be like the format of label2?

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

var label2 = ['28 Dec','29 Dec','30 Dec'];
var label3 = '28 Dec,29 Dec,30 Dec';

var data1 = '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0';

var lineChartData = {
    labels: label2,
    datasets: [{
        label: ' No. of clicks',
        backgroundColor: "lightblue",
        data: data1
    }]
}
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: lineChartData

});
```

I have made a code you could check it [here](http://codepen.io/thisisasample001/pen/dvgbPr)

Answer (score 0):

Your data1, label3 are strings, you have to use an array for that. Try to push you data in the array.

Comment: how can I push the data of label3, can you show me? i am quite new to this

Answer (score 0):

There is a small mistake that you made, your data variable should be an array. Something like this.

```
var data1 = [10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
```

Comment: with 28 Dec,29 Dec,30 Dec values how can I make it as an array ?

Comment: currently you have var data1 = '0,0,0';  to make this an array you have to change it to be var data1 = [0,0,0]