# How to select and pass array object to data setting of chart.js config?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, chart.js

I have a hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" id="0" value="10, 12">
```

and I am using

```
obj = [document.getElementById('0').value];
```

in a script tag to retrieve and use the value of the hidden input as the data array in the setting of Chart.js

```
const data = {
   labels: labels,
   datasets: [
      {
          backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
          data: obj,
          barThickness: 50
      }]
};
```

I have read [Chart.js unable to display data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067644/chart-js-unable-to-display-data) and [Treat getElementById return value as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757964/treat-getelementbyid-return-value-as-array) but both those questions answers suggest converting the object to an array which I have done and it still doesn't work.

[Not able to pass array of data to chart.js in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61516657/not-able-to-pass-array-of-data-to-chart-js-in-react) Was a react problem and I tried adapting it but it didn't work either.

The desired output I want can be seen in this code snippet here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<body>
    <canvas height="100px" id="myChart"></canvas>
    <input type="hidden" id="0" value="10, 12">
    <script>
        obj = [document.getElementById('0').value];
        console.log(Array.isArray(obj), obj);
        const labels = ['Type 1', 'Type 2'];
        const data = {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [
                {
                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
                    data: [10,12],
                    barThickness: 50
                }]
        };
        const config = {
            type: 'bar',
            data: data
        };
        const myChart = new Chart(
            document.getElementById('myChart'),
            config
        );
    </script>
</body>
```

How can I achieve the same solution by somehow selecting the hidden input and passing that array as the data?

I have used `console.log();` to confirm that the object is an array and that it has the correct value.

**Attempts**:

1. I've tried surrounding the object with **[]** like so `data: [obj],` but then nothing gets displayed (probably because it's already an array?)
2. I've tried converting the array to a list as suggested here: [Turn Array Into List With JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55766543/turn-array-into-list-with-javascript) but still nothing gets displayed.
3. I've tried changing the values of the hidden input to be `value="'10', '12'"` but still nothing gets displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of your hidden input is a string.

You are creating an array with a single element containing that string.

You need to split the string first, delimiting by the `,` character.

Trimming whitespace is also helpful too.

See below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<body>
    <canvas height="100px" id="myChart"></canvas>
    <input type="hidden" id="0" value="10, 12">
    <script>
        obj = document.getElementById('0').value.replace(" ", "").split(',')
        console.log(obj);
        const labels = ['Type 1', 'Type 2'];
        const data = {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [
                {
                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
                    data: obj,
                    barThickness: 50
                }]
        };
        const config = {
            type: 'bar',
            data: data
        };
        const myChart = new Chart(
            document.getElementById('myChart'),
            config
        );
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: This seems like a promising answer, I'm testing it now thank you for the answer.

Comment: Its worth noting that if you have control over the value of the hidden input you should omit the whitespace so it becomes `value="10,12"`. That way you can remove the `replace(" ", "")` when retrieving the value in your js.

Comment: Perfect this works, thank you so much @cam. I do have control over the value of the hidden input and will omit the whitespace. I'm accepting this answer because it is more readable and provides a code snippet however anfalt's answer also works.

Answer (score 2):

The line `obj = [document.getElementById('0').value];` will result in an array with the string "10, 12" as value. To convert the string to an array try split method: `obj = document.getElementById('0').value.split(",");`.

Now you have an array with the string values "10" and " 12". Not sure if chat.js can handle this, if not you can use the map funtion to iterate over the vales and covert the to numbers

Comment: Thank you @anfalt, that also works but I've accepted cam's answer as it's more readable and provides a code snippet. I would accept both answers if I could. Thanks for the help.